# Analysis of the bias resulting from PCA

Tags: pca, bias

Suppose that we generate some dataset from $y = X \beta + \epsilon,$ where $\epsilon$ is some independent error, and the rows of $X$ come from some distribution (unspecified for now). Suppose you run a PCA on a dataset $X$, resulting in $A$.

Can you characterize the bias you get from using $A$ instead of $X$, maybe in terms of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix (empirical or population) of $X$? I am familiar with the notion of PCA capturing a "fraction of the original variance," but not sure exactly how that translates to the bias when fitting a linear model. Any references or help would be great.

Comment: Won't this depend on the beta values? If the PCA-reduced matrix A strongly captures the y-determinative features of X, you'll get almost the same y values from using A instead of X. But if A contains only features that correlate to X-features with low beta weights, you can't recover y by using A. The problem is that how PCA utilizes the features has nothing to do with the y values at all, or how the linear model uses the features.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie - you might want to expand that into an answer, since it explains why the answer is "No."

Comment: "Bias" in what, exactly?  You aren't explicitly estimating anything.  And PCA captures 100% of the original variance, which sure looks unbiased!

Comment: PCA can be taken as a description of a sample, entailing that it isn't necessarily an estimator. And if it isn't necessarily an estimator then it isn't neessarily a [biased estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator). But sure, if your estimates of a population covariance are biased then in some sense your PCA results are a biased representation of some corresponding description of the population when those biased covariances are used.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that how the feature-reduced matrix $A$ approximates the full matrix $X$ depends only on the feature values of $X$ and has nothing at all to do with the target $y$. According to the beta matrix, some of your original features in $X$ will determine the value of $y$. If those original high-beta features have good correlates in $A$, then you'll be fine predicting $y$ from $A$. But if $A$ only adequately represents features from $X$ that are unrelated to $y$ through zero beta coefficients, using those features won't allow you to predict $y$ well at all.

As a concrete example, suppose beta = {0,0,1}. If $X_3$ happens to have high variance it will be well represented in $A$ and can be used to predict $y$. But if it's $X_1$ with high variance, that will dominate the feature-reduced matrix and won't help you predict $y$.